# Android Application Attachment with Gmail Show Application

Tags: java, android

I am facing a problem. 
Is it possible to  the save attachment file (.pdf and etc) from gmail to my application. After saved, the file will run directly from my application. After clicked save button in red circled, I wanted to run my application after attachment is saved in my download folder.

Note: I already able to download attachment into download folder.

Comment: You can set your application to receive `ACTION_VIEW` intents, that way, when you choose to download your attachment on GMail, you application will show up in the list of application to handle the attachment. You can use `getData()` to fetch the file. Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648096/if-my-app-was-started-via-action-view-how-do-i-retrieve-the-attached-data)

Comment: <intent-filter>
                                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
                                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
                                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
<data android:mimeType="application/pdf" android:scheme="file"></data>
</intent-filter> note: the code that I used

Comment: Thank You! already work with the link that you give! @FMontano